# Fields_for building each time I save infinitely

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have 2 models, Service and Subservice.

```
class Service < ActiveRecord::Base
    mount_uploader :teaser, TeaserUploader
    has_many :subservices
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :subservices, allow_destroy: true
end

class Subservice < ActiveRecord::Base
    mount_uploader :subicon, SubiconUploader
    belongs_to :service, dependent: :destroy
    validates_presence_of :service
end
```

I want each service to have many subservices, which I add through this form:

```
<%= simple_form_for @service do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :name  %>

   <%= f.fields_for :subservices do |builder| %>
     <%= builder.input :name, label: "Nombre Servicio", class: "form-control" %>
     <%= builder.input :description, label: "Descripción del servicio" %>
     <%= builder.input :subicon, label: "Icono" %>
  <% end %>
  <%= f.button :submit %>
<% end %>
```

It works fine, but each time I edit a new subservice, it gets duplicated instead of saving the old one. **It adds a new subservice to the form, instead of just editing the actual one.**

```
  # GET /services/1/edit
  def edit
    @service = Service.find(params[:id])
    @service.subservices.build 
  end
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

it's this line of code that does what you're saying:

```
@service.subservices.build
```

that tells Rails "build me a new subservice"

perhaps what you really want is:

```
@service.subservices.build if @service.subservices.blank?
```